# What is @MainActor in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

Is `@MainActor` just a syntactic sugar for `DispatchQueue.main.async` or else is there any other use to it?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/concurrency/how-to-use-mainactor-to-run-code-on-the-main-queue

Answer (score 5):

If we take a look at the declarations for both `UILabel` and `UIViewController`, we can see that they’ve both been annotated with the new `@MainActor` attribute:

```swift
@MainActor class UILabel: UIView
@MainActor class UIViewController: UIResponder
```

What that means is that, when using Swift’s new concurrency system, all properties and methods on those classes (and any of their subclasses) will automatically be set, called, and accessed on the main queue. All those calls will automatically be routed through the system-provided `MainActor`, which always performs all of its work on the main thread — completely eliminating the need for us to manually call `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Source: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-main-actor-attribute/

Comment: finally! 